# Google Maps API not drawing polylines

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to learn how to use the Google Maps API, and I've found a lot of good tutorials. Problem is, whenever I try to implement their code into my local HTML file, I don't see any polyline drawn on my Google Map.

Here's my code (note: I do have my API key in the script at the bottom):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 55.500, lng: 9.000},
            zoom: 10
          });
        }

        var encoded_data = "kpgiI}{wt@{xeDfxv@ylqC|flAyfyDidPiioBoabD_fkAyjfDooZ{nyCtw_BihCnzlBzbyAl}XehjBfp`B_se@vdgAhdPya_BoabDipHoabDngiAsen@jz}@htcAzqt@itcAnha@|~eBdzh@qqnBf~w@zrlCjkx@fppAy{u@zflA{zRpeuC`zWh`]bmx@}byAlwn@ny{DncNn}nDsxd@uqG";
        var decode = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_data);

        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: decode,
          strokeColor: '#00008B',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 4,
          zIndex: 3
        });

        line.setMat(map);
        lineArray.push(line);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing&key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading Google Maps API using:

```
<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

where

> The async attribute lets the browser render the rest of your website
>   while the Maps API loads. When the API is ready, it will call the
>   function specified using the `callback` parameter

In the provided example you are trying to utilize `google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath` function but `geometry` library could not be loaded at this moment.

There is a typo at line:

```
line.setMat(map); -> line.setMap(map);
```

**Fixed example**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 55.500, lng: 9.000 },
        zoom: 7

    });

    var encoded_data = "kpgiI}{wt@{xeDfxv@ylqC|flAyfyDidPiioBoabD_fkAyjfDooZ{nyCtw_BihCnzlBzbyAl}XehjBfp`B_se@vdgAhdPya_BoabDipHoabDngiAsen@jz}@htcAzqt@itcAnha@|~eBdzh@qqnBf~w@zrlCjkx@fppAy{u@zflA{zRpeuC`zWh`]bmx@}byAlwn@ny{DncNn}nDsxd@uqG";
    var decode = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_data);

    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: decode,
        strokeColor: '#00008B',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        zIndex: 3
    });

    line.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
 html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: The answer solved my problem. I am still unaware how you fixed it though. You mentioned that google.maps.geometry didn't load in time for the decode to use it's library, but I don't see any different in your example? Can you explain which part was changed to fix the problem?

Comment: Also; I tried to change the encode_data string to "{chwu@qikrIQUEKAIBKPEPAj@>h@>R>VG~MOjOMvQSdTSxUUbVWhVUbCCfCCtU}@`Lc@t@ChDMb@APLl@hBZlA`@dHVnFBh@VfD@PN`@HNPLNHp@LZDFL>N_@lBG`@IjAClABtAz@hIr@fG`AjGhAvHrAjIvAtJbBvKhBhLbBlLjBhLhBzLlB|LlBvL`BbLdBjL`AhLv@hKn@jKx@xK\\lKb@zJFdA]fO[lLYpLYrL_@~LU~LBlAx@tHzExOd@jAxAvClBnCdCjCzC~BpJhFrEhB`FzA~XxGxStElRjEvA\\hAXnErANDHFFFCLSHUDMHKLUJMDODO@_@BO>[AYCWEe@Qa@GME{@U[KIMIOO>OEOAVCqARqAJS@a@HILQDOK}", and now I don't get the line I want. It doesn't even show any line. Can you help me again please?

Comment: Regarding first question, except typo issue i've also placed `decodePath` function and `Polyline` object _inside_ `initMap` function since it is invoked  as callback

Comment: Regarding 2nd question, just posted [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32128906/1375553)  that demonstrates how to escape special characters