# Fixing encoded string for Google Maps polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an encoded string I want to use to draw a line in google maps, but Javascript can't read the string because of special characters such as the backslash. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with Javascript, and I have no idea how to escape these characters.

Encoded string:

```
qikrIehwu@WOKEIAIBGN?RAj@@f@?RGVO`NOhOSvQSdTUxUUbVUhVCdCEfC{@rUe@`LCt@KjDC`@NPfBl@nA\dH`@nFTh@BdDVPBb@LNJLNHPLn@B\NFNAlB_@^EjAKnAArABjIx@fGr@jG`AtHhAlIrArJxAvKbBhLfBnLdBhLjBxLfB|LnBxLjB`LbBlLdBfL~@hKv@lKn@vKx@lK\|Jd@dADfO[lL]pLWrLY~L_@~LWlABtHx@xOzEjAf@vCxAlCjBjCfC`CxChFrJfBrEzA`FxG~XtEvSlElRZvAXhAtApEDNDHHDLAFSFUFMLMLUDKBO@OB_@?Q?YC[GUOg@I_@COUy@M[MKMG?OEQAOCVPoALsA@QHa@JIDSKO
```

What I've tried so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Filtered Data</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: { lat: 55.570, lng: 9.000 },
          zoom: 13
        });

        RegExp.escape = function(s) {
          return s.replace(/\\/g, '&#92;');
        };

        var encoded_data = RegExp.escape("qikrIehwu@WOKEIAIBGN?RAj@@f@?RGVO`NOhOSvQSdTUxUUbVUhVCdCEfC{@rUe@`LCt@KjDC`@NPfBl@nA\dH`@nFTh@BdDVPBb@LNJLNHPLn@B\NFNAlB_@^EjAKnAArABjIx@fGr@jG`AtHhAlIrArJxAvKbBhLfBnLdBhLjBxLfB|LnBxLjB`LbBlLdBfL~@hKv@lKn@vKx@lK\|Jd@dADfO[lL]pLWrLY~L_@~LWlABtHx@xOzEjAf@vCxAlCjBjCfC`CxChFrJfBrEzA`FxG~XtEvSlElRZvAXhAtApEDNDHHDLAFSFUFMLMLUDKBO@OB_@?Q?YC[GUOg@I_@COUy@M[MKMG?OEQAOCVPoALsA@QHa@JIDSKO");
        var decode = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_data);

        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: decode,
          strokeColor: '#00008B',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 4,
          zIndex: 3
        });

        line.setMap(map);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no issue with that encoded Polyline. There is no need to escape anything. Just enclose the string within simple `'` or double `"` quotes and it will work.

```
function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: {
            lat: 55.570,
            lng: 9.000
        },
        zoom: 10
    });

    var encoded_data = 'qikrIehwu@WOKEIAIBGN?RAj@@f@?RGVO`NOhOSvQSdTUxUUbVUhVCdCEfC{@rUe@`LCt@KjDC`@NPfBl@nA\dH`@nFTh@BdDVPBb@LNJLNHPLn@B\NFNAlB_@^EjAKnAArABjIx@fGr@jG`AtHhAlIrArJxAvKbBhLfBnLdBhLjBxLfB|LnBxLjB`LbBlLdBfL~@hKv@lKn@vKx@lK\|Jd@dADfO[lL]pLWrLY~L_@~LWlABtHx@xOzEjAf@vCxAlCjBjCfC`CxChFrJfBrEzA`FxG~XtEvSlElRZvAXhAtApEDNDHHDLAFSFUFMLMLUDKBO@OB_@?Q?YC[GUOg@I_@COUy@M[MKMG?OEQAOCVPoALsA@QHa@JIDSKO';

    var decode = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_data);

    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: decode,
        strokeColor: '#00008B',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        zIndex: 3
    });

    line.setMap(map);
}

initialize();
```

Proof of concept fiddle:

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/g391fmaw/)</kbd>

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/K05gEJS.png) is what it looks like in your example and [this](http://i.imgur.com/8ONoRPH.png) is what it's supposed to look like, when I escape the special characters.

Comment: How did you encode the polyline in the first place is the real question to ask and you haven't provided any details about that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, in your example `encoded_data` variable contains some special characters (e.g. `\`) that need to be escaped.

You could utilize [JavaScript String encoding - Online tool](http://www.htmlescape.net/stringescape_tool.html) for that purpose, in that case the string:

```
qikrIehwu@WOKEIAIBGN?RAj@@f@?RGVO`NOhOSvQSdTUxUUbVUhVCdCEfC{@rUe@`LCt@KjDC`@NPfBl@nA\dH`@nFTh@BdDVPBb@LNJLNHPLn@B\NFNAlB_@^EjAKnAArABjIx@fGr@jG`AtHhAlIrArJxAvKbBhLfBnLdBhLjBxLfB|LnBxLjB`LbBlLdBfL~@hKv@lKn@vKx@lK\|Jd@dADfO[lL]pLWrLY~L_@~LWlABtHx@xOzEjAf@vCxAlCjBjCfC`CxChFrJfBrEzA`FxG~XtEvSlElRZvAXhAtApEDNDHHDLAFSFUFMLMLUDKBO@OB_@?Q?YC[GUOg@I_@COUy@M[MKMG?OEQAOCVPoALsA@QHa@JIDSKO
```

will be encoded to:

```
qikrIehwu@WOKEIAIBGN?RAj@@f@?RGVO`NOhOSvQSdTUxUUbVUhVCdCEfC{@rUe@`LCt@KjDC`@NPfBl@nA\\dH`@nFTh@BdDVPBb@LNJLNHPLn@B\\NFNAlB_@^EjAKnAArABjIx@fGr@jG`AtHhAlIrArJxAvKbBhLfBnLdBhLjBxLfB|LnBxLjB`LbBlLdBfL~@hKv@lKn@vKx@lK\\|Jd@dADfO[lL]pLWrLY~L_@~LWlABtHx@xOzEjAf@vCxAlCjBjCfC`CxChFrJfBrEzA`FxG~XtEvSlElRZvAXhAtApEDNDHHDLAFSFUFMLMLUDKBO@OB_@?Q?YC[GUOg@I_@COUy@M[MKMG?OEQAOCVPoALsA@QHa@JIDSKO
```

**Modified example**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 55.570, lng: 9.000 },
        zoom: 11
    });

    var encoded_data = "qikrIehwu@WOKEIAIBGN?RAj@@f@?RGVO`NOhOSvQSdTUxUUbVUhVCdCEfC{@rUe@`LCt@KjDC`@NPfBl@nA\\dH`@nFTh@BdDVPBb@LNJLNHPLn@B\\NFNAlB_@^EjAKnAArABjIx@fGr@jG`AtHhAlIrArJxAvKbBhLfBnLdBhLjBxLfB|LnBxLjB`LbBlLdBfL~@hKv@lKn@vKx@lK\\|Jd@dADfO[lL]pLWrLY~L_@~LWlABtHx@xOzEjAf@vCxAlCjBjCfC`CxChFrJfBrEzA`FxG~XtEvSlElRZvAXhAtApEDNDHHDLAFSFUFMLMLUDKBO@OB_@?Q?YC[GUOg@I_@COUy@M[MKMG?OEQAOCVPoALsA@QHa@JIDSKO";
    var decode = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_data);

    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: decode,
        strokeColor: '#00008B',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        zIndex: 3
    });

    line.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
html, body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

**Another example**

```js
        var map;

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 55.570, lng: 9.000 },
                zoom: 13
            });

            var encoded_data = document.getElementById('encodedPolyline').value;
            
            var decode = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_data);

            var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: decode,
                strokeColor: '#00008B',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 4,
                zIndex: 3
            });

            line.setMap(map);
        }
```

```css
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

 #map {
    height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing"></script>
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Encoded Polyline:</td>
                <td><textarea id="encodedPolyline" class="encodeBox"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <input type="button" value="Draw Polyline" onclick="initMap()" />
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't always have a hardcoded string, I am going to get them from the database, so I need a function (or regex) which can replace special characters such as the \

Comment: In that case there is no explicit encoding is required, see the updated answer (another example): post an original encoded string and click 'Draw Polyline' button, the proper path should be rendered